# Visual Studio 2012 InstallShield LE - How to specify target folder on different drive for web app

Tags: installshield-le

I am using the InstallShield Limited Edition which comes with VS 2012 (after install). Anyway I would like to know how to specify the Content Source path on my target system to be on a different drive than the C drive. Specifically I want my content files to be at D:\MyAppFolder.